# Python Airflow bigquery 400 configuration.query.createDisposition cannot be set for scripts

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, airflow

Recently I started getting an error in my *BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator* (`from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator`)

```py
execute_query_job = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
                        task_id = "execute_query_job_{}".format(destination_table),
                        use_legacy_sql = False,
                        sql = sql_query,
                        destination_dataset_table = destination_table,
                        create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                        write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                        dag = dag
                    )

job_id_execute = execute_query_job.execute(context=context)
```

The above code block works how it suppose to work, so it is working fine. But when I change my `sql_query` to a new one I am getting the `Error 400: configuration.query.createDisposition cannot be set for scripts`.

`SQL` script which works for the code block,..

```sql
with data_table as(
    select pltfm_name, event_dt as event_date
    from `project_id.dataset.data_tabele`
    AND event_dt BETWEEN  DATE('start_date',"America/Los_Angeles") AND DATE('end_date',"America/Los_Angeles")
),
activity_data as (
    select DATE(timestamp, "America/Los_Angeles") as event_date,
    COUNT (distinct CASE WHEN eventid = 'mp' AS bp
    from `project_id.dataset.data_tabele`
    AND DATE(timestamp, "America/Los_Angeles") between DATE("start_date","America/Los_Angeles") AND DATE("end_date","America/Los_Angeles")
    group by 1
),
cal as (
    select event_date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE("start_date","America/Los_Angeles"), DATE("end_date","America/Los_Angeles"))) event_date
)
select a.event_date,
coalesce(c.bp, 0) as bp,
from cal a
left join activity_data c on a.event_date = c.event_date;
```

But the below `SQL` script doesn't work and it'll give an error.

```sql
DECLARE
  temp string DEFAULT 'D';
  SET temp = 'M';
WITH
  BASE_DATA AS (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN temp = 'M' THEN DATE_TRUNC(EventDate,MONTH)
      WHEN temp =  'Q'THEN DATE_TRUNC(EventDate,QUARTER) 
  END
    ed,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN temp = 'M' THEN tl
            WHEN temp = 'Q' THEN tl
     END) AS tl_count
  FROM
    `project_id.dataset.data_table`
  WHERE
    CASE
      WHEN temp = 'M' THEN (DATE(EventDate) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), MONTH), INTERVAL -2 MONTH) AND DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
      WHEN temp = 'Q' THEN (DATE(EventDate) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()), QUARTER), INTERVAL -2 QUARTER)
      AND DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), QUARTER), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
  END
  GROUP BY
    1
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC)
SELECT
  ed,
  tl_count
FROM
  BASE_DATA
ORDER BY
  ed DESC;
```

So the above `SQL` script throws the error, but runs perfectly in `GCP BigQuery`. I have looked around and it seems Airflow can't execute the query with a `DECLARE` statement or something similar. (Kind of similar issue --> https://www.py4u.net/discuss/174607). I have tried what they suggested but it still didn't work, end-up with the same error. So, now I am not sure what causing the issue here and if there is another way to approach this in `Airflow`.

Does anyone know what might be happening and a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've surmised, the DECLARE statement means that there's multiple discrete steps in this SQL text, so this is executed as a SCRIPT rather than a single statement: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

The easiest thing is probably to remove the job config properties related to destination table/dispositions and instead update the final `SELECT ...` to be a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

Comment: Hey @shollyman, do you know any other Airflow operators which can handle this kind of script?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py#L493 it seems that BigQueryInsertJobOperator is the preferred successor.